# why I am getting "Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program." exception while loading a simple page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I have an Asp.Net MVC 3 application hosted and running in Microsoft Azure. Recently I have started getting an exception like this
[image]

I have checked the server instance and it has 2 gb free memory available. The strange thing is that I have another web application hosted in the same virtual machine instance and it is running perfectly.

I have done restarting the server and it helps, but I don't want to do it every time. I want to know the root cause.

Comment: What do you have in your `Global.asax` file? Are you doing any application initialization that's different from your working app?

Comment: @Yuck: no, in global.asax file we have added some routing configuration and some certificate initialization.